# How to move Zepplin Notebooks from old version to new version?

Tags: apache-zeppelin

How to move Zepplin Notebooks from old version to new version?

Config: Ubuntu; Zepplin(0.6.2) to (0.7.3)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sampath,

Export, import.

On notebook on 0.6.2, click [Export the notebook](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FtINB.png)

This will get you a json type file.  Now go on to your 0.7.3 Zeppelin landing page and click 'Import Notebook' [Import note](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zM4qS.png).

Comment: Can you please suggest for a bulk process? Thanks.

Comment: Inside Zeppelin Directory, there is a notebook directory, inside which, there is a directory per notebook.  You could try shutting new zeppelin instance down and copying all these notebook directories to the new install and restarting the server.  G'luck

Answer (score 0):

Just putting this here in case I can help others.

You can do bulk operation via command line. Just go to zeppelin config, find out about notebooks directory path. Then copy your notebooks there. (they have folders with note.json in it)

You may need to change the ownership to zeppelin user after copy finished.

Then go back to zeppelin ui and there is a small refresh botton at top of notebooks page. There is no restart or shutdown required.

Comment: I'm using Zeppelin running on the server of my university which restricts me to access the config tab. Do you think I would be able to upload all of my notebooks via a command line from another notebook?

Comment: You need ssh access for this

Comment: I do have ssh access. Could you please tell me how can I find the location of the Zeppelin notes on the server then.